# Can a friend class object access base class private members on a derived class object in its member function?

Tags: c++, class, friend

How object of Derived class `D d` can be accessed in friend class of `Base B`?

Since there is no relationship between `D` and `F` then how it is possible to 
access private member `b_var` of object of `D` in friend class?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class B {              //Base class
    int b_var;
    friend class F;
};

class D : public B {    //Derived Class
    int d_var;
};

class F {              //This class is a friend class of B
public:               //So it should access objects of B Not Derived Class 
    void func(D &d) {      // object LIke in example d    
        d.b_var = 5;
        cout << "I accessed D's Private Member b_var :" << d.b_var;
    }
};

int main()
{
    cout << "fine";
}
```

Comment: `b_var` is still a member of the class that `friend`s `F`. Inheritance has nothing to do with it, notice that `d_var` will be inaccessible to `F`.

Comment: @George: Are you sure that "b_var is still a member of the class that friends F"? `b_var` is private and I think `private` members are not inheritable.

Comment: @Raindrop7 Yep i'm sure. If `private` members weren't inheritable then inheritance would be pretty useless, as any private state of a parent would be lost.

Comment: @George No! I don't agree. Base class's private data are not accessed from  derived child classes. (private data of a base class is not a part of derived class ).

Answer (score 1):

> Since there is no relationship between D and F then how it is possible to access private member b_var of object of D in friend class?

`F` has access to the base `B` of the class `D`, because it is a public base. Furthermore, `F` has access to private members of `B`, including `b_var`, because `F` is a friend of `B`. Thus, `F` has access to `b_var` that is a member of the base `B` of the class `D`.

Perhaps it helps to visualize the accessibility to use a more qualified name lookup. `d.b_var` is same as `d.B::b_var`.

Comment: But friendship in C++ is not inheritable. So how can `d.b_var` is accessed from `F`?

Comment: @Raindrop7 Friendship not being inheritable is irrelevant. `F` doesn't need to be a friend of `D`, because it is already a friend of `B`, and `b_var` is a member of `B`.

Comment: No. It is wrong! So can you prove that class F can access `d_var` which is a member of class `D`?  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend

Comment: @Raindrop7 What is wrong? I can prove that `F` can **not** access `d_var`. This is because  `d_var` is not a member of `B`, and so the friendship relation between `F` and `B` is irrelevant to accessing `d_var`. Pay close attention to difference between `d_var` and `b_var`. They look very similar.

Comment: But you said: "Friendship not being inheritable is irrelevant. F doesn't need to be a friend of D, because it is already a friend of B, and b_var is a member of B.".

Comment: @Raindrop7 That's what I said indeed. It doesn't conflict with anything else, does it?

Comment: @Raindrop7 Are you trying to get points for yourself… This answer is a good as yours and direct to the point so I don't understand your comments as in the end, your answer mostly say the same thing anyway but a few hours later...

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is that class `F` is a friend of class `B` which means it has full access to its members; `private, protected, public`.

Class `D` is a child of class `B` it inherits all members of class `A` but `private` members. So trying to access private base class members will issue an erorr eg:

```
class D : public B{
    void func(){
        std::cout << b_var << std::endl; // error cannot access private members
    }
};
```

As you can see `D` is derived from `B` but cannot access `b_var` because it is `private`.

You can make it access it if you declare the child to be friend of the parent:

```
class B{
    int b_var;
    friend class D;
};

class D : public B{
    public:
        void func(){
            cout << b_var; // ok now! because D is friend of its parent then it has access to its private data.
        }
}
```

In your example class `D` is a child of class `B` so it cannot access `b_var` because it is private. But class `F` has full access to the class `B` so it can access its `private, public, protected` members:

```
class B{
    int b_var = 10;
    friend class F;
};

class D : public B{
    int d_var;
};

class F{
    public:
        void func(D d){
            cout << d.b_var; // it is a hack to encapsulation here

            B b;
            cout << b.b_var << endl; // ok here because F is friend of B.
        }
};
```

As you can see above that that `F` has full access to class `B` it uses a `D` object and granted to it this privilege. Normally `D` cannot access `B` private data but `F` grants access to it.

- Friendship is not transitive (a friend of your friend is not your friend)
- Friendship is not inherited (your friend's children are not your friends)
- Friendship is not commutative (being me your friend doesn't mean being you my friend necessarily).

Comment: i understand what you @Raindrop7 are saying. But the problem here is that d is the object of Derived class. And Friend F has no link with derived classes objects. that is why i am thinking that b_var wont be accessible in class F being the object of class D.